# Get type of inherited instantiated template

Tags: c++, templates

Is it possible to obtain the type of an instantiated template from a variable?

```
struct A { enum E {A_, B, C}; };
struct B { enum E {X, Y, Z}; };

class BaseClass {};
template <typename T> class TemplateClass : public BaseClass {};

class AChild : public TemplateClass<A> {};
class BChild : public TemplateClass<B> {};

template <typename T>
class WorkerClass
{
  static void do_stuff(const BaseClass& a) {}
};

int main(void)
{
  AChild a;
  //need to call WorkerClass<A::E>::do_stuff(a)
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may do:

```
template <typename T>
void foo(TemplateClass<T>& c)
{
    WorkerClass<typename T::E>::do(c)
}
```

and then

```
foo(a);
```

Other traditional way is to add the type in template class:

```
template <typename T> class TemplateClass : public BaseClass
{
    using type = T;
};
```

so you can do

```
WorkerClass<AChild::type::E>::do(a);
```

Comment: @yes, it is since `AChild` is not a class template but an instantiation of a class template.

Comment: I ended up aliasing the type, it was the most straightforward solution.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to obtain the type of an instantiated template from a variable?

Yes.

1. Update the class template to provide the type that was used to instantiate it.

   ```
   template <typename T> struct TemplateClass : public BaseClass
   {
      using type = T;
   };
   ```
2. Use `decltype(A)` to use the type of `A`.

---

Here's an updated version of your posted code that compiles and builds for me using g++ 5.4.0.

```
struct A {enum E{AA, AB, AC}; };
struct B {enum E{BX, BY, BZ}; };

class BaseClass {};

template <typename T> struct TemplateClass : public BaseClass
{
   using type = T;
};

class AChild : public TemplateClass<A> {};
class BChild : public TemplateClass<B> {};

template <typename T>
struct WorkerClass
{
  static void dostuff(const BaseClass& a) {};
};

int main(void)
{
  AChild a;
  using type = decltype(a)::type;
  WorkerClass<type::E>::dostuff(a);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

C++ has **RTTI** (Run Time Type Identification). Maybe you want to use `std::dynamic_cast` for this.

dynamic_cast(elem) tries to get an object of type T from elem

- If T is of type pointer, it returns a pointer to the object, or 0 (if
  the pointed object is not of type T)
- If T is of type reference, it returns a reference to the object, or
  throws an std::bad_cast exception

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @Jarod42 's answer, you may also write a type trait instead, in C++11:

```
template <typename T>
T& GetEnumOfImpl(TemplateClass<T>&);

template <typename T>
using GetEnumOf = typename std::decay_t<decltype(GetEnumOfImpl(std::declval<T&>()))>::E;

...

AChild a;
WorkerClass<GetEnumOf<AChild>>::do_stuff(a);
```